# ios game make a mask layer effect

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

[image]I need a 'mask' layer that covers the whole screen, with the center part (a circle) to be transparent. Then I can move the mask layer around using touch. User are only able to see the transparent part in the middle.

I don't think a png file can help because the file need to be very large to cover the whole screen.

So is it possible to do it by coding?

i found this online, but don't know much about openGL.  http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/7921.

it would be great if i can use a CCMaskLayer and input with the radius. i can handle the touch event by my self.

the attached png file is expected result, the center part is transparent. i need this to cover my screen, and only show the middle part. the red part is covered.

Comment: This link might help u http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/87296-how-do-i-mask-jpeg-when-they-dont-support-transparency.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I write a CCMaskLayer to do the exactly same thing.

https://github.com/smilingpoplar/CCMaskLayer

Answer (score 3):

You may solve this task with cropped circle texture in two ways:

1) Draw sprite with circle texture in screen center and draw another 4 sprites around (on top, bottom, left and right sides) with small red texture but scaled to cover all screen.

2) (more elegant but harder to implement) Make your mask layer fullscreen but adjust texture coordinates. In details:

- set wrap mode to `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` to your circle texture
- adjust texture coordinates of your layer vertices (to do this you need to subclass base `CCLayer`):

  [image]

Here `v` means vertex position and `t` - texture coordinates. You need to set correct texture coordinates for four corner vertices of layer. For future if you will want to drag circle you will need to add some offset values to texture coordinates.

Comment: the first solution do u mean that i can scale the other 8 squares freely? so i can just use a small png file and scale it up? as far as i know, scaling is very expansive. and the transparency might change :(

Comment: Yes. You even may use sprites with common white texture and colored into red.

Comment: thanks for ur answer, but i am still waiting for openGL solutions since they are more elegant such that i can easily change the shape in the middle etc (by coding instead of fixed png file)